# SQL Query for closest match at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Am currently using Mysql and PHP.

Looking for a query that will take a number and find the closet match for the begining of a set of digits, for example I have the number `019235678910, 026725678910, 026825678910` and my table looks like this.

```
Table - Destintation

Name     Number
Watford  01923
Oxford   026
Romford  026
Crawford 0267
Topford  02672
```

So when I pass `019235678910` the result would be `Watford`, `026725678910` would be `Topford` and `026825678910` would be `Oxford` and `Romford`.

I'm also not sure if MYSQL can do this directly or would need to work in conjunction with PHP?

Comment: See this question. I think it's identical problem: **[Walking a BTREE index as far as possible in MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29849/walking-a-btree-index-as-far-as-possible-in-mysql)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select maximum length of matching string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687168/mysql-select-maximum-length-of-matching-string)

Answer (score 2):

Here one way for getting all of them:

```
select d.*
from Destination d join
     (select length(Number) as maxlen, number
      from destination d
      where YOURVALUE like concat(Number, '%')
      order by maxlen desc
      limit 1
     ) dsum
     on d.Number = dsum.Number
```

Because you are looking for initial sequences, there is only one maximum match on the numbers (hence the `limit 1` works).

By the way, the field called `number` is clearly a character field.  Personally, I think it bad practice to call a character field "number" -- something called cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Number
FROM Destintation
WHERE LEFT('026725678910', LENGTH(Number)) = Number
```

or perhaps

```
WHERE '026725678910' LIKE CONCAT(Number, '%')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, this works but not exactly how I wanted it as the number 026725678910 instead of just returning Topford as the closet match it also returns Oxford, Romford and Crawford. Cheers